# Scrolling ListView like in TweetDeck

Tags: android, listview, scroll, adapter

I was wondering if anyone knows how the scrolling in TweetDeck can be done. In particular how they did it so that the last item can be scrolled up to the top of the listview.

I think this is kinda awesome and would like to use such a behavior in my app too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a listview. It is TimelineView class which inhert view class. You can decompile dex file and check it.